# Swagger spec in Swagger Core Jersey 1.X

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am using Swagger with Jersey 1. It generates spec in Swagger spec v1.2. Most of the tools out there (e.g. [Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) ) require spec v2.0. Is there a way to generate spec v2.0 ?

I actually wanted printable/static docs like [bootprint-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootprint-swagger) which also required spec v2.0.

Comment: Here is the answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917188/how-to-break-swagger-2-0-json-file-into-multiple-modules/26917653#comment48850926_26917653

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter seems to be able to convert Swagger 1.2 to Swagger 2.0

I'm not sure if it is an "official" Swagger-Tool, but it is just two clicks away from [the Swagger-1.2-to-2.0-Migration-Guide](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/wiki/Swagger-1.2-to-2.0-Migration-Guide), so I guess its like "half-official" at least.

I might try to incoorporate it into `bootprint-swagger` so that it supports Swagger 1.2 as well. I've just created [an issue at github](https://github.com/nknapp/bootprint-swagger/issues/21) so that it is not forgotten.