# How can I slice main swagger.js and include them back?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

## swagger.js

[image]

I have `swagger.js` it contain `100,000` lines of codes. It contain about 50 sections of routes.

## Yep, 100,000 lines

You guys can imagine how brutal it is to even look at it.

Example.

[image]

## I’m thinking

to slice my main file into peaces and include them back.
I would prefer crate a : `swagger/` inside that, I will place `section1.js` , `section2.js` ,... `section50.js` .

## Benifits

- When I need to add more section in the future, I can just create one more js. Ex. `newSection.js`
- When I need update a tiny thing, I can just go into that specific section, and update it without to messed around with `100,000` lines of codes.
- It’s much more easier to maintenance.
- It’s less CPU intensive for my IDE. My computer fan went nuts when I open that file.
- Faster to find what to modify/add

Can someone please show me to get start on that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break Swagger 2.0 JSON file into multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26917188/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [yamlinc](https://github.com/javanile/yamlinc) to split the file into multiple files referencing them with `$include` properties and compile back again.

Comment: By the quick look of it, it seems pretty cool. Are you personally using one on your project ?

Comment: Not, but it seems pretty stable.